# How to read configuration that contains a "Name" attribute using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, microsoft.extensions.configuration

I am trying to read a configuration in my application.

Consider the code below...I load an XML in memory and it contains 3 different nodes.
I can only get the value of the node with no `Name` attribute

```cs
      const string content = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<configuration>
  <node1 Name=""something"" Foo=""Bar"" />
  <node2 NoName=""something"" Foo=""Bar"" />
  <node3 Name=""ignored"" NoName=""something"" Foo=""Bar"" />
</configuration>";
      var doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml(content);
      using var stream = new MemoryStream();
      doc.Save(stream);
      stream.Position = 0;
      var configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddXmlStream(stream)
        .Build();

      var node1 = configurationRoot.GetSection("node1").Get<Node1>();
      var node2 = configurationRoot.GetSection("node2").Get<Node2>();
      var node3 = configurationRoot.GetSection("node3").Get<Node2>();
```

And the `Node` classes

```
    private class Node1
    {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    private class Node2
    {
      public string NoName { get; set; }
      public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
```

The configuration has 3 nodes,
`node1` contains the attribute `Name` and I am trying to read it using Node1

`configurationRoot.GetSection("node1").Get<Node1>()` does not populate the values.

`node2` does not contain the attribute `Name` and I am trying to read it using Node2

`configurationRoot.GetSection("node2").Get<Node2>()` populate the values as expected.

Finally, `node3` does contain the attribute `Name` but I am trying to read it using Node2, (that does not care about the name).

`configurationRoot.GetSection("node3").Get<Node2>()` also does not populate any of the values.

How can I read a node that contains a `Name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7a45201181d37329b7ab0bee541ed7c42b5d94b6/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml/src/XmlStreamConfigurationProvider.cs#L221) shows that the `Name` attribute gets a special treatment.

```
// The special attribute "Name" only contributes to prefix
// This method retrieves the Name of the element, if the attribute is present
```

In short, the value of the `name` attribute is being included in the (section/item) key.

To retrieve `node1` you need to call

```
var node1 = configurationRoot.GetSection("node1:something").Get<Node1>();
```

For `node3` that is

```
var node3 = configurationRoot.GetSection("node3:ignored").Get<Node2>();
```

---

The debug visualizer in Visual Studio for `configurationRoot` shows these keys.

[image]

---

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#xml-configuration-provider) explains the concept of this `Name` attribute and shows some examples about when and how to use.

> In .NET 5 and earlier versions, add the name attribute to distinguish repeating elements that use the same element name. In .NET 6 and later versions, the XML configuration provider automatically indexes repeating elements.

Comment: Thanks, that a but inconvenient to be honest, I was hoping there would be a way around it, (via a config flag or a custom builder/provider). I can write my own method to get the value, but it does not feel right.

Comment: Well, this is what the out of the box implementation behind `AddXmlStream` does. If that doesn't fit, you'll indeed have to come up with some custom code. You might consider using an alternative for `Name` to bypass that behavior; e.g. `Key` or `Identifier`.